# How to pass then() return object as input to then() function using NodeJS Map function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am new working with NodeJS, I am able to extract JSON file from my local file system, using MAP function we have to perform 2 functions sequentially. For this first function result should be input for second function using .then().

Can you please help me with sample code.

Comment: Read this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show some code.  Your words are not very clear.  Code would help a lot to understand how you're trying to use `.map()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand what you mean, but chaining several promises works like this:

```
computeResultOneAsyncronously()
    .then(function(resultOne) {
        return computeResultTwoAsynchronously(resultOne);
    }).then(function (resultTwo) {
        return computeResultThreeAsynchronously(resultTwo);
    }).then(function (resultThree) { 
      // and so on */
    };
```

Applying two functions on array elements consecutively with `.map()` works like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
function f1(x) { return x + 1 }
function f2(x) { return x * 2 }
var result = arr.map(f1).map(f2);
// yields [4, 6, 8, 10]
```

I hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: but there's no **map** in your answer!! are you a witch? :p

Comment: You are right. I don't understand what the `map` should apply to since the question is not really clear. However, I'll add an example.

Comment: I was being funny :p